# Short If use in Python-Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm building a website in Python and want to write a simple `<select>` box.

Here's my code:

```
<td>Posts Per Page</td>
<td>
    {{ g.blogOptions['posts_per_page'] }}
        <select name="posts_per_page">                        
            {% for counter in range(5, 20, 5) %}
                <option value="{{counter}}" {{ "selected=true" if counter == g.blogOptions['posts_per_page'] else '' }}> {{ counter }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
</td>
```

On the line 3 of this code, it prints `10` but in the `for` loop it doesn't hit the `if` and doesn't write `selected=true`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `{% if %}`/`{% endif %}`:

```html
<select name="posts_per_page">                        
    {% for counter in range(5, 20, 5) %}
        <option value="{{counter}}" {% if counter == g.blogOptions['posts_per_page']  %} selected="selected" {% endif %}> {{ counter }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Make sure that `g.blogOptions['posts_per_page']` is an integer; if it is a string instead, you'll need cast it:

```
{% set posts_per_page = int(g.blogOptions['posts_per_page']) %}
<select name="posts_per_page">                        
    {% for counter in range(5, 20, 5) %}
        <option value="{{counter}}" {% if counter == posts_per_page  %} selected="selected" {% endif %}> {{ counter }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: yes you are right it may be,but now it says UndefinedError: 'int' is undefined

Comment: @Gandalf: sorry, indeed, if statements are limited; just a sec.

Comment: @Gandalf: Interesting; the Jinja2 docs state it is available. What version of jinja are you using? How is `g.blogOptions` set, can you set it to an `int` elsewhere?

Comment: i changed its type in my py file and it printed <type 'int'> for g.blogOptions['posts_per_page'] and my jinja2 version 2.6

Comment: dude it's working now,i changed it's type in wrong block,sorry about my mistake,thanks for the answer :))